# Two common ways to increase vocabulary -- which is more efficient?

Tags: learning-methods, english, vocabulary

I just wondered how I can increase vocabulary to be able to communicate better and enjoy magazines, books and news programs in English.I have two vocabulary workbooks that contain around 2000 words respectively along with their definitions, pronunciations and example sentences; typical vocabulary books you might have read to pass SAT or GRE, though mines are much easier.However, some say it's scientifically more efficient to stay away from messing around with such workbooks and expand vocabulary only by reading materials(preferably written in plain English, such as Time for Kids) that are written in "real" English, that is to say, the very combination of words, phrase and sentences that are actually used by native speakers, while looking up unknown words in a learner's dictionary from famous publishers like Cambridge or Oxford press. Then which way should I go for, cramming with vocabulary books or learning "naturally" via contexts?

Comment: A big part of this is about what is interesting to you. Perhaps reading workbooks and doing the exercises is more efficient, but if it is extremely boring as well, will it work? Same for "easy" language like things written for kids, and so on. Perhaps you will learn some interesting words "naturally", but if the content itself is too boring, then again, can it really sustain you long-term? Ultimately, only you as a learner can decide these things, so I don't think there's any one correct answer. I would consider using a variety of materials and "methods" in your learning.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense; I prefer reading books to cramming with workbooks and thus should focus on what I really enjoy.I'll try grabbing some books and taking up reading to see how my vocabulary improves.Thank you.

Comment: Any reading in English works. Just read and look up words you don't know. But it's also good to hear the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I can increase vocabulary while reading easy literature works for young native speakers while enjoying the learning process itself, because it doesn't make much sense to cram with workbooks if it's a bit boring.